# Can we point godaddy DNS to aws s3 static website?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-s3, godaddy, amazon-route53

I have a domain example.com which is registered in godaddy . 
I have hosted a static website in s3 bucket .my s3 endpoint is

```
<bucket-name>.s3-website-<AWS-region>.amazonaws.com .
```

I want to point example.com to my s3 website. If I transfer my domain to aws route53 it will charge for a hosted zone. I don't want to pay for a hosted zone. So I need to point example.com to my s3 website. Can I do this in godaddy?

Answer (score 3):

I am not really sure what you mean by this, but if you are asking if you can point `alias.example.org` via CNAME to `mybucketid.s3.aws.com` (or whatever they are called, don't use this) from an external DNS provider, the answer is yes.

The only thing you could only do from within Amazons service would be to set reverse records, as these have to be set or delegated by the owner of the net block.